# assign the returned pointer to a new array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new c-programmer. I defined a function, which parse a line and generates token. Each of these token will be saved in an array of tokens. So  I created an array of Strings for that purpose. My defined function returns this Array. Now I want to assign the returned array to a new array I get an error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[5]’ from type ‘char **’.
```

So I do not have any idea how to deal with this problem. here is the whole code;

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **  parseLine(char * str){
    char del[2]=",";
    char * token;
    //Array of strings
    char * tokenArr[5];
    token=strtok(str,del);
    int i=0;    
    while(token!=NULL && i<5){
        //save each new token in the array of tokens
        *(tokenArr+i)=*token;
        token=strtok(NULL,del);
         i++;
    }
    return tokenArr;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv []){
    char str[120]="Achon, Adkins, 3459345,cs,usa";
    char * tokenArray [5];
    tokenArray=parseLine(str);
}
```

Comment: why return pointer to a pointer? `char *` should work.
`char *  parseLine(char * str)` should solve the issue.

Comment: @amitakCs You should dynamically allocate an array in the function and in main also use a pointer of the same type.

Comment: yes, @amitakCs pointed correctly. `char * tokenArr = new char *[5];` create the array dynamically.

Comment: Educate yourself about containers, it may help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: I am trying to use pure c

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Those work in C?

Comment: @amitakCs: It is not possible to assign anything to an array in C language. Arrays in C are not assignable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C language it is not possible to "return" a value of array type from a function. It is not possible to "assign" or in any other way copy an array using core language features.

In your situation a common practice is to pass the destination array to the function as a parameter and fill it out inside the function. The return value of your function might be used to return the actual number of tokens to the user

```
unsigned parseLine(char * str, char *tokens[], unsigned max_tokens)
{
  char del[2] = " ,";

  char *token = strtok(str, del);
  unsigned i = 0;    

  while (token != NULL && i < max_tokens){
    tokens[i++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, del);
  }

  return i;
}
```

You will call your function as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char str[120] = "Achon, Adkins, 3459345,cs,usa";

  char *tokenArray[5];
  unsigned n_tokens = parseLine(str, tokenArray, 5);

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n_tokens; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", tokenArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use pointers, so I modified a little bit the while-loop: *(token+i)=token; i+=1;

Comment: @amitakCs: Both variants "use pointers". `[]` operator is just syntactic sugar over `+` and `*` operators.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assing a char to a char pointer here:

```
*(tokenArr+i)=*token;
```

`token` is a pointer, so assign it, not the value it points to.

In the function, you are trying to return a local array `tokenArr`. Returning an array and/or returning a local variable is not possible. Return a pointer to an array that is allocated on the heap instead:

```
char** tokenArray;
tokenArray=parseLine(str);
```

---

```
char** parseLine(char* str){
...
char** tokenArr = malloc(sizeof(*tokenArr)*5);
...
return tokenArr ;
}
```

As you fix this, think about checking return values of the functions you call, for invalid values. And then how are you going to know how much elements did you actually process and how are you going to obtain that information.

Comment: Yes I was about to comment:even if this compiles the array of string pointers returned by the function goes out of scope, even destroyed, when the function exits.

Comment: token is pointing to a string. So that why I used dereference operator to get the string and assign it to the array of strings

Comment: @amitakCs That will give you the first character. The string "is" where the pointer points to.

Comment: Another solution would be to pass the array declared in `main()` as an argument to `parseLine()`.

Comment: If my pointer points to the first element of string, then i can go over other elements by moving the string